# After rails upgrade migration entry are getting delete from schema migration table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-6.1

After upgrading from rails 5.1 to rails 6.1 the entries are getting deleted from the schema_migrations table except for the last entry.

I am facing this issue in all the environments. For the test environment, I fixed the test environment by commenting on this line **ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!** but in the development and non-production environment, I am still facing the issue.

I try to google it but I don't see any article related to it. Could anyone give some insight on it?

Rails 6.1.0 
ruby 3.0.0 
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter 6.1.4
Database Oracle

Comment: I have the same issue with a Rails Engine 6.1.4.1, with a postgresql database. There's a smell at this level, it seems it's db agnostic: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26948

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the migrations if you have no pending changes.

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you

> Migrations, mighty as they may be, are not the authoritative source
> for your database schema. Your database remains the authoritative
> source. By default, Rails generates db/schema.rb which attempts to
> capture the current state of your database schema.
>
> It tends to be faster and less error prone to create a new instance of
> your application's database by loading the schema file via bin/rails
> db:schema:load than it is to replay the entire migration history. Old
> migrations may fail to apply correctly if those migrations use
> changing external dependencies or rely on application code which
> evolves separately from your migrations.